# How do I get the duration of the codec video file that prefix .264 using the FFmpeg library?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I use FFmpeg library for android ndk. There is no problem when I run .mp4 format video. Actually, I play the video file that has the .264 suffix. However, when I run .264 format video, the code returns a negative number like that -232132.

this is code:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_lscodex_just_videoplayertesting2_H264Decode_getDuration(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

  AVFormatContext *formatContext = gvs->pFormatCtx;

    if (NULL != formatContext) {


         int durations = static_cast<jint>(formatContext->duration / AV_TIME_BASE);
         logd("VIDEO DURATION ---> %d", durations);
         return durations;
     } else {
         return -1;
     }
}
```

the output is VIDEO DURATION ---> -2077252342

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: @szatmary sorry that, I have edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant find a reference to the error code `-2077252342`. But it can't determine the duration of the .264 because .264 does not have/encode a duration into the file. That is the containers job. If it is constant frame rate, you can multiply he frame rate by the number of frames to get the duration. i.e. `frame_count * (1/frames_per_second)`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to sum all packet durations in the raw h264 stream but that requires reading the whole file.

Doing this with ffprobe is something like this:

```
ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries packet=duration_time -i file.264
```